# Have network always wait for a network connection?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way to tell Ubuntu Server to constantly wait for an ethernet connection after it gets disconnected?

Use case: Ethernet cable gets unplugged (intentionally) for a long period of time, cable gets plugged back in, computer must be forcefully restarted to get on the network again

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig` immediately after reconnecting the cable?

Comment: Please provide more information on how you are 'starting' the ethernet service to begin with.  The default behavior of most drivers is to remain ready to link up whenever a cable is plugged in.  Also, which version of ubuntu and which ethernet card?